Nodejs Cookie is set to empty value
I am using nodejs for backend, the backend is hosted on renderon and the frontend is hosted on netlify.
I am trying to set the cookie in this way
  res.cookie("spare_auth_token", token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true, // Should be true only if you're using HTTPS in production
  sameSite: "none", // This allows cross-site cookies
  maxAge: 7200000, // Cookie expiration in milliseconds (2 hours)
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7200000), // Optional, explicitly setting expiration date
  domain:  process.env.SHORT_FRONTEND_DOMAIN ,
});

when i check my browser in the frontend i find the cookie with the specified name but the value is empty , and in the sameSite tab i find this hint
"this set-cookie didn't specify a samesite attribute and was default to samesite=lax and was blocked"
I logged the token on production and it is not empty.
any idea why is this happening ?
